# Proc.new binding change and loops logic abstraction

Tags: ruby

I've two loops in two different methods which look very similar. I wanted to abstract most of their logic in a `Proc.new`

**This works**

```
def matches_base?
  proc_exec = Proc.new do |subclass, breakpoint|
    # next and return are meant to act inside the loop and quit it if needed
    response = process_match(subclass)
    next if response == :continue
    return true if response == false

    return response
  end

  subclasses(BASE_NAMESPACE).each do |subclass|
    proc_exec.call(subclass)
  end
  false
end
```

The obvious issue here is the `proc_exec` is defined inside the method itself, but I want to use it in another method

```
def matches_breakpoints?
  breakpoints.fetch.each do |breakpoint|
    # I want to include the proc_exec here too
  end
  false
end
```

So I just tried to extract it at the class level like so

**This does not work**

```
def proc_exec
  Proc.new do |subclass, breakpoint|
    response = process_match(subclass)
    next if response == :continue
    return true if response == false

    return response
  end
end

def matches_base?
  subclasses(BASE_NAMESPACE).each do |subclass|
    proc_exec.call(subclass)
  end
  false
end
```

Then I could have called it like `proc_exec.call` from within both instance methods. Currently it throws

```
 LocalJumpError:
   unexpected return
```

I tried many tricks such as `instance_eval` or `instance_exec` without success. I'm out of solution right now.

---

**Easily executable, simplified example of what I want below.**

```
class MyLoops
  def proc_exec
    Proc.new do |num|
      next if num == 1
      # we want this `return` to act in the method context
      # as it would do if I defined it inside a method directly
      return if num == 4
      puts "Current number : #{num}"
    end
  end

  def method_a
    [0,1,2].each do |num|
      proc_exec.call(num)
    end
    false
  end

  def method_b
    [3,4,5].each do |num|
      proc_exec.call(num)
    end
  end
  # this `false` below should never be reached ; that's the trick
  false
end

loops = MyLoops.new
loops.method_a
loops.method_b
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: **do not use `return` in ruby save for early returns**.

Comment: Can you compose a [mcve]?

Comment: @mudasobwa: one could argue that _every_ return is an early return. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev _“early return’_ is an idiom, like _“fail fast”_ in [tag:erlang] :)

Comment: @mudasobwa the final loop return is to quit the method before it reaches the ending `false` it was all thought beforehand, there is a reason for everything here

Comment: @SergioTulentsev wait i'll work on making something simple you can try

Comment: @Laurent: yep, that snippet was very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have your cake and eat it too. If you want `return` from the proc to abort the method, it must be in the method's lexical scope* (which is another way to say "it must be defined within the same method").

An alternative is to have proc/lambda return a "stop" value, which caller will use to abort its execution.

(Your experiments with instance_eval/instance_exec were misdirected, sadly. Those methods only change current `self`. This problem has nothing to do with current `self`, but rather current lexical scope, in which `return` is executed.)

---

<sup>* The error you're getting, it is caused by `return` trying to return from a method that is no longer running (`proc_exec`).</sup>

Comment: Yes, this essentially repeats mudasobwa's (now deleted) answer, but with less code. Unfortunately, there seems to be no magic trick that could work here.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, that's why I asked and now I've the confirmation ... Escaping with a stop (trick) seems to be the cleanest solution ...